# UriMatcher matching wilcard? (Crash in Android mail app)

Tags: android, uri

I get a crash in the android mail app which I traced back to the UriMatcher failing to match an URI.

The relevant code:

```
UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
sURIMatcher.addURI(EmailContent.AUTHORITY, "uiattachmentbycid/#/*", UI_ATTACHMENT_BY_CID);
int match = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
if (match < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
}
```

This fails with

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown uri:
> content://com.android.email.provider/uiattachmentbycid/4127/assets/img/filiale-icon@2x.png

See https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/134e092c9b71d8145ba8c7540bac0c392630218f/provider_src/com/android/email/provider/EmailProvider.java#L1223 for the full source

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: `EmailContent.AUTHORITY` seems to be being set up strangely, so perhaps somehow it is not matching `com.android.email.provider`.

Comment: I put a debug printf there and the authority is indeed com.android.email.provider
It seems the issue is the different amount of slashes. Checking the code for UriMatcher it iterates over all uri-components and trys to find a matching node. The added URI only matches "content://com.android.email.provider/uiattachmentbycid/4127/assets" but everything after that has no matching part. I.e. the "*" does not match slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an actual bug in the EMail app itself.
The Mail-Source in this case contains `<img src="cid:assets/img/filiale-icon@2x.png">` and an attachment with `Content-ID: <assets/img/filiale-icon@2x.png>`

According to RFC 2045 and 822 this is valid:

- `id := "Content-ID" ":" msg-id`
- `msg-id      =  "<" addr-spec ">"`
- `addr-spec   =  local-part "@" domain`
- `local-part  =  word *("." word)`
- `word        =  atom / quoted-string`
- `atom        =  1*<any CHAR except specials, SPACE and CTLs>`
- `CHAR        =  <any ASCII character>        ; (  0-177,  0.-127.)`

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#appendix-D

So slashes are very much allowed here.

Hence the UriParser cannot be used here as the last part (the star) can contain slashes which the UriParser cannot handle